# UICollectionView and selected UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to do a simple `UICollectionView` with a custom cell composed of an `UIImageView` and an `UIView` above.

When a cell is not selected, the `UIView` on the top of the cell have is `backgroundColor` property set to `UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)`.

I have issues with the selection. The `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method is called but when I change the `UIView` described previously, nothing happen.

Here is the code of my `collectionView` :

```
class TestCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController
{
    var items = [1, 2, 3]

    let cellId = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return items.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!
    {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId,
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestingCollectionViewCell

        let item = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img")
        cell.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
    {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId,
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestingCollectionViewCell

        cell.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
    {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId,
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestingCollectionViewCell

        cell.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    }
}
```

If this snippet is not enough, here is [my project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/db8aanyy6izj5zc/FuckingCollectionView.zip)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not be dequeuing a new cell in didSelectItemAtIndexPath (or in didDeselect either) -- this is creating (or reusing) a new cell, not getting the one you selected. Use this instead,

```
var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, been struggling with it for a while! However, my new image gets drawn in the middle of the UICollectionView, not in the cell I clicked on. Any idea why?

Comment: @kakubei What new image are you asking about? Are you asking about the imageView.image or the overlayView?

Comment: I crate a me imageView with image for that cell and on a reloadData the image moves to another cell. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @kakubei You should ask a question, and show what code you're using. I can't give you a good answer without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

To me the following code worked better (the code of rdelmar crashed sometimes, which might be a bug? in Swift):

```
(collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as myCollectionViewCellType).uiBackground?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Edit: I forgot to mention: My collectionView-Items are based on their own class to which I cast. uiBackground is an element of that class

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        {

    //saving index path of the image loaded from imageproperty_array            
      selected_imagepath = imageproperty_array[indexPath.row] as String

    //saving index of the selected cell item as Int            
      selected_imageindex = indexPath.row

        }
```